# libstreaming - videoQuality not being set

Tags: android, video-streaming, google-glass, rtsp, libstreaming

I am developing an app to stream live video from an android device via RTSP using the libstreaming library.

I am trying to change the video quality by using the following code:

```
  private void initRtspClient() {
    mSession = SessionBuilder.getInstance()
        .setContext(getApplicationContext())
        .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_NONE)
        .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
        .setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(480, 360, 30, 500))
        .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView).setPreviewOrientation(0)
        .setCallback(this).build();
```

but when the app is running on the device I am getting the following error in the logs:

```
12-16 12:03:32.601    4596-4609/com.example.GlassApp E/EncoderDebugger﹕ No usable encoder were found on the phone for resolution 480x360
12-16 12:03:32.601    4596-4609/com.example.GlassApp E/H264Stream﹕ Resolution not supported with the MediaCodec API, we fallback on the old streamign method.
```

But this is the resolution stated in the `Suppored Media Format` doc (enoding in h.264) http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

What is the problem?

EDIT: Should probably add the android platform is Google Glass (XE22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only seemed to be able to change the resolution to the following two values:

```
    .setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(640, 480, 20, 500000))
```

or

```
    .setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(960, 720, 20, 500000))
```

The code did not seem to work if the framerate was raised over `20` fps either.